# Creation of dynamic payload in groovy script

Tags: json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I have to create a json payload using groovy which will be like-

```
{
  "source":1,
  "target":0 
}
```

And the source and target values would change dynamically starting from 0. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonBuilder` to create the required json as shown below.

```
//Define value or assign it dynamically for target and source as shown below
def tValue = 0
def sValue = 1

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json {
  source sValue
  target tValue
}
println json.toPrettyString()
```

You can quickly try it online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/9f3R1l)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Usually nice to use **JsonOutput**. You can build json from map:

```
def map = [source:1, target:0]
def out = new groovy.json.JsonOutput()
println out.prettyPrint(out.toJson(map))
```